# Is it possible to query a database using a value passed in a URL, and write the result of the query to the URL using mod_rewrite?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to use mod_rewrite to write an htaccess rule that takes a url parameter value (for example: id=1, where 'id' is the parameter, and '1' is the parameter value), query a database with the parameter value specified, and then write the value returned from the query as a part of the url of the requested page?

I know the basics of mod_rewrite, for example rewriting a url that appears like:

```
www.example.com/item.php?id=1
```

to the following:

```
www.example.com/item/1
```

An example of what I would require is writing the following url:

```
www.example.com/item.php?id=1
```

to this:

```
www.example.com/item/name-of-item-based-on-id-specified-in-original-url
```

However I have no idea if what I am looking to do is possible using mod_rewrite.

If anyone has a solution to this problem I'd be very grateful if you could help me. If what I am trying to do is not possible using htaccess and mod_rewrite, can someone please point me in the direction of how I may go about solving this problem?

Comment: What is your desired result? Show an example.

Comment: Thanks @TobiasKun...I have now provided an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible, but you need to use a [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) to define a mapping that you can use within a `RewriteRule`.

Apache version 2.2 doesn't have direct database access so you'll need to write a script that does the actual query then return the result. You can define this map using the ["External Rewriting Program"](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html#prg).

So if you have a script that takes "cats" from stdin, then queries the database, and returns "1", you'd define it like so:

```
RewriteMap item_lookup prg:/path/to/item_lookup.php
```

That directive has to be in your server or vhost config, it can't be in an htaccess file. But you can use the mapping in an htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /item.php?id=${item_lookup:$1} [L]
```

So this takes the URI `/cats` and rewrites that to `/item.php?id=1`.

If you are using apache 2.4, then you can take advantage of the ["DBD" map](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html#dbd). You can insert a query right into the map definition, bypassing having to use an external script. You'd use it in the same way.

```
RewriteMap item_lookup "fastdbd:SELECT id FROM items WHERE name = %s"
```

Then use it in the same way:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /item.php?id=${item_lookup:$1} [L]
```

Without using a DBD/FastDBD query, I think you're honestly better off just doing the database lookup from `item.php`, since you'd be duplicating all of that work in a second external script anyways. Just add something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^item/([0-9]+)$ /item.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ /item.php?name=$1 [L]
```

And in your `item.php` script, check for both **id** and **name**. If you have a **name**, do the database lookup in order to turn that into an id. It's much easier to manage, you don't need to have server/vhost config access, and you're not complicating matters by using a rewrite map.

Comment: This is a very neat feature. Did not know about this. Is this save against mysql-injections?

Comment: @TobiasKun Only if you sanitize in the external program, otherwise, yes, you can sqli into the DBD query.

Comment: @TobiasKun To be more specific, [mod_dbd goes over some of the issues](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dbd.html#security) with sqli