# How do I change the url look with .htaccess but keep the php functionality?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to learn, so please be kind. My site is database driven and uses ID numbers to generate the pages. I'd like the URL not to show the ID number but the name of the page. Is there a way to do this where it is just cosmetic and doesn't effect the site? I'm also most likely screwing up the way I'm writing the redirect as it doesn't seem to work at all? What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

This is how my URL looks now:

`http://mydomainname.com/index.php?id=35-Entertainment`

I'd like it to look like this:

`http://mydomainname.com/Entertainment`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/d]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunate there is not a way to do this.

The process in this case is the following:

1. A user enters the a url. In this case you want a nicely formatted URL (http://mydomainname.com/Entertainment)
2. The user sends this url to your server
3. Apache processes the url and points it to your project directory based on the domain used in the url
4. There Apache uses the htaccess to see what to do next. In this case the best method would most likely be to use `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]` or something like that
5. Then you need to do the routing within your app. You can use a routing table for instance to map the nicely formatted slug to an module/id combination

This process can't be done by Apache for it does not known about the content present in your database.

Hopefully this is of any help for you.

Comment: There is a way to do it using [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap)

Comment: Thank you, it does help a bit, can you point me in the right direction to understand more about the routing you mentioned in #5?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thanks for pointing that one out. Based on its documentation it can be used but if I read it correct it would be difficult to maintain for a dynamic page site, unless you generate the mapping file based on your database.

Comment: @Taryn Sure. You would write a dispatcher for handling the URL with is provided and will land in your application on index.php?url=... (for the htaccess example a gave) . An example of how a dispatcher may use this is, is that of CakePHP 1.3. It is rather simple and old, but that makes a bit more easier to understand. https://github.com/littleant/cakephp-1.3.21/blob/master/cake/dispatcher.php. If you really would like to build more complex applications I would suggest to use a framework like Symfony. There you have Dispatchers for routing build in.

Comment: @Bearwulf [you can use a db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18621538/is-it-possible-to-query-a-database-using-a-value-passed-in-a-url-and-write-the) through your right its not advised but is far from not supported like your saying.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone That is a really nice trick. Didn't know you could use it to that extend and that makes it a lot more flexible. It would a bit odd to implement than the more used methods, but its good to know its possible :)